# elasticsearch сортировка по полю с массивом чисел

Tags: elasticsearch

Есть необходимость отсортировать данные по полю, в котором массив из чисел.
Например, есть данные:

```
[1, 32, 26, 16]
[1, 32, 10, 1500]
[1, 32, 1,  16]
[1, 32, 2,  17]
```

Результат нужен такой:

```
[1, 32, 1,  16]
[1, 32, 2,  17]
[1, 32, 10, 1500]
[1, 32, 26, 16]
```

У elasticsearch есть режими сортировки: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_option. Но ни один из вариантов не подходит, так как:

- min даст сортировку по числу 1, а как же другие числа
- max отсортирует по 32
- sum сортировать будет по сумме чисел, что тоже неверно
- avg тоже отрабатывает не так как нужно.

Если в языке ruby попробовать отсортировать тот же набор, получается ожидаемый результат, так как есть метод [<=> в классе Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), в описании которого cказано "Each object in each array is compared"

Как такое же сделать с помощью elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Так как сортировка таких массивов в эластик работает не так, как ожидалось, пришлось составить дополнительное поле в индексе, куда записываются номера в стиле: "0001 0032 0026 0016". В таком случае сортировка работает ожидаемым образом. Вот только надо заранее знать какое максимальное число во всех этих массивах.
Решение не из лучших, но других не нашёл